# PHP/SQL if variable contains string which is the same as x characters in table column

Tags: php, sql

I have a variable which contains multiple dates as string. It's a range of dates. When I send this into the database table, I want to check if the column contains one of these dates. This is hard to do because a variable is a string of multiple dates. Every date excists out of 10 characters. So I send a variable as string into a database which contains multiple or a single date and I want to check if there already is one of those dates which excist out of 10 characters, so if 10 characters without a space between are the same.

Example of a column:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUiIK.png

```
    $query_overeenkomst = "SELECT * from $stad WHERE beschikbare_data LIKE '%$date%'" or die(mysql_error());
    $result_overeenkomst = mysqli_query($conn, $query_overeenkomst);
    $rows_overeenkomst = mysqli_num_rows($result_overeenkomst);
    if($rows_overeenkomst>=1){
    echo "There is a match!";
    }
    else
    { 
    echo "No date the same.";
    }
```

If I use this code, the column has to contain the **whole** string of $data (which contains all the dates), but I want to check if there is only one or more dates that match.

The data variable:

```
$data .= $date->format("Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
```

Returns for example:

```
2018-12-19 2018-12-20 2018-12-21 2018-12-22 2018-12-23 2018-12-24 2018-12-25
```

Comment: Updated the post. @HtmHell

Comment: Use an array, not a string. Then each date will be its own data point. You also should parameterize your query.

Comment: You should note store delimited data in the DB. 1 data point per column. Also, and unrelated currently but `mysql_error` will not help you with `mysqli` and might make your code stop working if your upgrade to PHP 7. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$dates = str_replace(PHP_EOL, "','", trim($data));
$query_overeenkomst = "SELECT * from $stad WHERE beschikbare_data IN ('$dates')";
```

The query variable will have the following content:

```
SELECT * from WHERE beschikbare_data IN ('2018-12-19','2018-12-20','2018-12-21','2018-12-22','2018-12-23','2018-12-24','2018-12-25')
```

Which will select all rows with the listed dates.

**EDIT:**
After fuguring out that you store your in the database the list of dates in one row the answer will be different.

First, you should know that it's a terrible database structure design, you should read about many-to-many relationship.

In any case, this is how you can solve this without changing any structure:

```
$dates = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($data));
$where = "";

foreach ($dates as $key => $date) {
    $where .= ($key > 0) ? " OR " : "";
    $where .= "beschikbare_data LIKE ('%$date%')";
}


$query_overeenkomst = "SELECT * from $stad WHERE $where";
```

This will result this SQL query:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE beschikbare_data LIKE ('%2018-12-19%') OR beschikbare_data LIKE ('%2018-12-20%') OR beschikbare_data LIKE ('%2018-12-21%') OR beschikbare_data LIKE ('%2018-12-22%') OR beschikbare_data LIKE ('%2018-12-23%') OR beschikbare_data LIKE ('%2018-12-24%') OR beschikbare_data LIKE ('%2018-12-25%')
```

Notice that this is an extremly slow query, and in order to avoid this you must change your data structure design.

Comment: It looks like the DB is new line separated as well so the `like` will be required (`in` would require an exact match).

Comment: @user3783243 Thanks, I haven't noticed that, I thought those were different rows. I will update my answer in a bit.

Comment: Im getting this error: `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: @beauvandermeer That doesn't sound like an error you'd get from a `select` query.

Comment: @HtmHell I don't know why, but it returns this error `Error: INSERT INTO den_haag (`gnummer`, `beschikbare_data`) VALUES ('44', '2018-12-19','2018-12-20','2018-12-21','2018-12-22','2018-12-23')
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` Using `$sql = "INSERT INTO $stad (`gnummer`, `beschikbare_data`)
  VALUES ('$klantnummer', '$dates')" or die (mysqli_error($conn)); `

Comment: You probably edited your code in the wrong place, we are talking about the `SELECT` query, not the `INSERT`

Comment: I know, but I changed $data from the insert query to $dates, or should it still be $data?

Comment: @beauvandermeer Just copy & paste my code. It should look like this: https://pastebin.com/mgb2XhaC

Comment: @HtmHell sorry, forgot to say, but eventually it worked perfectely. Thanks.